# Snapshot not compatible with the current VM configuration Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am added Flutter to my existing Andoird app.

when I run App in **release** mode, App crashes with the following exception. But it works perfectly in **debug** mode

> Error while initializing the Dart VM: Snapshot not compatible with
>   the current VM configuration: the snapshot requires 'product
>   use_bare_instructions no-"asserts" causal_async_stacks arm64-sysv' but
>   the VM has 'product use_bare_instructions no-"asserts"
>   causal_async_stacks arm-eabi softfp'

As per [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19865#issuecomment-409437378) thread. I added

```
ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(["x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi-v8a", "armeabi"])
        }
```

but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`? What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: Yes. I tried....Flutter 1.2.1.. and Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

Comment: Have you added the product flavors to your Flutter project gradle?

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29284